# dynamic button handle click in dynamic table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page with multiple tabs. On each tab pressed, my script is executing `php` page which returns a table with results. That page is then returned to `JS` script and is inserted into HTML page.

Here is my `php` script:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../db/db_handler.php');
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../util/util.php');

$table = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true)['id'];
?>

<html>
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 2%" scope="col">#</th>
        <th style="width: 15%" scope="col">Street</th>
        <th style="width: 10%" scope="col">Phone</th>
        <th style="width: 10%" scope="col">Date</th>
        <th style="width: 15%" scope="col">Price</th>
        <th style="width: 38%" scope="col">Comment</th>
        <th style="width: 10%" scope="col">Operator</th>
        <th style="width: 10%" scope="col">Worker</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    <?php
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM `" . $table . "` ORDER BY `date` ASC");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();



    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $tr_id = $table . $row['id'];

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<th class="align-middle" scope="row">' . $row['id'] . '</th>';
        echo '<td class="align-middle">' . $row['street'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="align-middle">' . $row['phone'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="align-middle">' . format_date($row['date']) . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="align-middle">' . $row['price'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="align-middle">' . $row['comment'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="align-middle">' . $row['operator'] . '</td>';

        if (!isset($row['worker'])) {
            echo '<td>' . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Accept</button>' . '</td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td>' . $row['worker'] . '</td>';
        }

        echo '</tr>';
    }
    ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

And here is my page with `Tabs`:

```
<div class="tab-pane show" id="dr" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="city-dr">
 <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center" id="tab-city" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: x-large; text-transform: uppercase" id="city-dr" data-toggle="tab" href="#dr" role="tab" aria-controls="dr" aria-selected="true">City 1</a>
  </li>

  <li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: x-large; text-transform: uppercase" id="city-bor" data-toggle="tab" href="#bor" role="tab" aria-controls="bor" aria-selected="false">City 2</a>
  </li>
 </ul>

 <div class="tab-content" id="city-content">
  <div class="tab-pane show" id="dr" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="city-dr">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center m-2" id="tab-table" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: x-large; text-transform: uppercase" id="<?php echo Tables::$table_dr_repair ?>" data-toggle="tab" href="#dr-repair-content" role="tab" aria-controls="dr-repair-content" aria-selected="false">Repair</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: x-large; text-transform: uppercase" id="<?php echo Tables::$table_dr_fttb_pull_in ?>" data-toggle="tab" href="#dr-fttb-pull-in-content" role="tab" aria-controls="dr-fttb-pull-in-content" aria-selected="false">FTTB Pull In</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: x-large; text-transform: uppercase" id="<?php echo Tables::$table_dr_fttb_weld ?>" data-toggle="tab" href="#dr-fttb-weld-content" role="tab" aria-controls="dr-fttb-weld-content" aria-selected="false">FTTB Weld</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
     <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: x-large; text-transform: uppercase" id="<?php echo Tables::$table_dr_ftth ?>" data-toggle="tab" href="#dr-ftth-content" role="tab" aria-controls="dr-ftth-content" aria-selected="false">FTTH</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
    
   <div class="tab-content" id="dr-table-content">
    <div class="tab-pane show active" id="dr-repair-content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="city-dr"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane show active" id="dr-fttb-pull-in-content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="city-dr"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane show active" id="dr-fttb-weld-content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="city-dr"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane show active" id="dr-ftth-content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="city-dr"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
    
 <div class="tab-pane show" id="bor" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="city-bor">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills justify-content-center m-2" id="tab-table" role="tablist">
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: x-large; text-transform: uppercase" id="<?php echo Tables::$table_bor_repair ?>" data-toggle="tab" href="#bor-repair-content" role="tab" aria-controls="bor-repair-content" aria-selected="false">Repair</a>
   </li>
    <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: x-large; text-transform: uppercase" id="<?php echo Tables::$table_bor_fttb_pull_in ?>" data-toggle="tab" href="#bor-fttb-pull-in-content" role="tab" aria-controls="bor-fttb-pull-in-content" aria-selected="false">FTTB Pull In</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: x-large; text-transform: uppercase" id="<?php echo Tables::$table_bor_fttb_weld ?>" data-toggle="tab" href="#bor-fttb-weld-content" role="tab" aria-controls="bor-fttb-weld-content" aria-selected="false">FTTB Weld</a>
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" style="font-size: x-large; text-transform: uppercase" id="<?php echo Tables::$table_bor_ftth ?>" data-toggle="tab" href="#bor-ftth-content" role="tab" aria-controls="bor-ftth-content" aria-selected="false">FTTH</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
    
  <div class="tab-content" id="bor-table-content">
   <div class="tab-pane show active" id="bor-repair-content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="city-bor"></div>
   <div class="tab-pane show active" id="bor-fttb-pull-in-content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="city-bor"></div>
   <div class="tab-pane show active" id="bor-fttb-weld-content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="city-bor"></div>
   <div class="tab-pane show active" id="bor-ftth-content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="city-bor"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And here is my JS Script I use for handling tab clicks:

```
$('#tab-table a').on('click', async function (e) {
        let data = {
            id: e.currentTarget.id
        };

        let response = await fetch('/main/repository/fetch_tasks_table.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        });

        document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.href.split('#').pop()).innerHTML = await response.text()
    });
```

As you can see, in my `php` part, where the table is being echoed, I have a button showed in certain cases.

What I want to do:

- (bad solution) make that button execute certain php script and then reload whole page
- (much better solution) make that button change the color of the `row` of table that it was clicked on, the make button disappear, on it its place, we display some text and do some changes in MySQL DB by executing some php script with fetch() or by any other means.

Please help me figure this out

Edit: My thought process and where I am stuck.

Okay, so if we follow the thought proceess of `much better solution` we end up with the following problems:

- We need to change the color of the `row` where the button was clicked. How should the JS function know which `row` was it? Also, how would JS function know the `row` of which `table` was clicked?
- We need to hide the button and show some text instead of the button. How would I access the parent where `button` is nested (`<td>` tag) to insert some text into it when the button is hidden?

Comment: Well, you've pretty much figured it out in `(much better solution)`. What is the exact problem you're facing?

Comment: @El_Vanja I edited my post and added some info at the bottom of the post; Duplicate: 
Okay, so if we follow the thought proceess of `much better solution` we end up with the following problems:

- We need to change the color of the `row` where the button was clicked. How should the JS function know which `row` was it? Also, how would JS function know the `row` of which `table` was clicked?

- We need to hide the button and show some text instead of the button. How would I access the parent where `button` is nested (`<td>` tag) to insert some text into it when the button is hidden?

Comment: You've just pointed yourself in the right direction. If you do a search of "get parent of element", you'll end up at MDN's [parent element page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement). That's how you solve which row as well - you take the clicked button and find its parent.

Comment: wow, it was that simple and I was that close

Comment: @El_Vanja Thank you very much! I got it from here